# Full screen application causes screen saver to not start (Lion)

Tags: macos, screensaver

When I am in a Full Screen application mode, the screen saver doesn't start. So I have to shift to another screen that doesn't show a full screen app. There the screen saver starts!

This naturally happens only in Lion.

Comment: is it a feature?

Comment: lion is a buggy peace of work, a reinstall of the os will probably do the trick the easiest way, no need for a "factory restore" just a reinstall, also try enabling and disabling the screensaver settings

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to assign a Hot Corner to start the screen saver. To do this, go to `System Preferences > Desktop & Screen Saver > Screen Saver > Hot Corners…` and select "Start Screen Saver" in the drop down menu of your choice.

(Side note: Hot Corners is also accessible from the Mission Control prefpane.)